# Parsing xml in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

This is my part of xml file

```
 <IOStatusSummary>
         <iostatus_interval_value>
               <count>0</count> 
              <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-01-16 15:45:30">1.0</iostatusvalue> 
              <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-01-16 19:47:29">0.0</iostatusvalue> 
               <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-05-16 13:01:07">1.0</iostatusvalue> 
               <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-05-16 18:51:33">0.0</iostatusvalue> 
               <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-05-27 16:45:50">1.0</iostatusvalue> 
                <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-05-27 20:56:00">0.0</iostatusvalue> 
                 <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-06-10 10:21:28">1.0</iostatusvalue> 
                 <iostatusvalue datainterval="2016-06-10 20:01:17">0.0</iostatusvalue> 
         </iostatus_interval_value>
 </IOStatusSummary>
```

what i am trying to do is

```
DocumentBuilder db1 = DocumentBuilder db1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is1 = new InputSource();
    is1.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlResult));
    Document doc1 = db1.parse(is1);

    NodeList nList_interval=doc1.getElementsByTagName("iostatus_interval_value");          

     List on = new ArrayList();
     List off = new ArrayList();

      for (int =0; i < nList_interval.getLenght(); i ++ ){

       Node currentItem2= nList_interval.item(iter);

         Element element2 = (Element) currentItem2;

         String iostatusvalue = element2.getElementsByTagName("iostatusvalue").item(i).getTextContent();

      if(iostatusvalue.equals("1.0"))
       {
 on.add(element1.getAttribute("datainterval")));                                                           

       }


       if(iostatusvalue.equals("0.0"))
        {    

  off.add("element1.getAttribute("datainterval"))");

        }

       }
```

then i am printing i am expecting

> on = { 2016-01-16 15:45:30" , 2016-05-16 13:01:07 , 2016-05-27
>   16:45:50,2016-06-10 10:21:28}
>
> off = { 2016-01-16 19:47:29, 2016-05-16 18:51:33, 2016-05-27 20:56:00,
>   2016-06-10 20:01:17 }

i am getting my list are empty and above xml is not complete xml its part of xml.

But i am not getting what i am expecting i think i making logical mistake somewhere because i am new in this.

Thank for reading my question.

Comment: What is what you get?

Comment: Your XML is invalid. It starts with a closing tag

Comment: Thats my typing mistake

Comment: i am getting both list are empty.

Comment: What is `iter` and where do you define it? Your looping makes no sense to me.

Comment: @shreerambanne Have you tried to use a Debugger to find out what is happened?

Comment: This i am doing in my jsp script so no eclipse to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String xml = "<IOStatusSummary><iostatus_interval_value><count>0</count><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-01-16 15:45:30\">1.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-01-16 19:47:29\">0.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-05-16 13:01:07\">1.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-05-16 18:51:33\">0.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-05-27 16:45:50\">1.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-05-27 20:56:00\">0.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-06-10 10:21:28\">1.0</iostatusvalue><iostatusvalue datainterval=\"2016-06-10 20:01:17\">0.0</iostatusvalue></iostatus_interval_value></IOStatusSummary>";
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    DocumentBuilder db1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc1 = db1.parse(bais);

    NodeList nList_interval = doc1.getElementsByTagName("iostatus_interval_value").item(0).getChildNodes();

    List<String> on = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> off = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nList_interval.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nList_interval.item(i);
        if (element.getTagName().equals("iostatusvalue")) {
            String text = element.getTextContent();
            String interval = element.getAttribute("datainterval");
            if (text.equals("1.0")) {
                on.add(interval);
            }
            if (text.equals("0.0")) {
                off.add(interval);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(on);
    System.out.println(off);
```

The main difference in this example is this line:

```
NodeList nList_interval = doc1.getElementsByTagName("iostatus_interval_value").item(0).getChildNodes();
```

What this does is to get a list of all the child elements of the first `iostatus_interval_value` element.